# Passing data between screens with AsyncStorage

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, asyncstorage

I am developing a messenger app and I am trying to do a search of friends by email. So when the user enters another user's email in Prompt text field, typed email compares with those on the server and if a match is found, then it creates a new chat with new friend on server, as well as in the app.

I have one screen called Messages.js and second screen called firebaseChatModule.js which is responsible for all Backend processes. What I need to do: if a match is found, then pass typed email to Backend. I tried to do that with AsyncStorage, but the issue is: every time I receive null instead of email.

How can I fix it and are there any other simple ways how I could do that?

Screenshots: Messages.js: [image: Messages.js]

firebaseChatModule.js: [image: firebaseChatModule.js]

upd:

Okey, now it works, thx to Nirmalsinh for the answer, but now I get following issue on the server:

[image]

User1 is the email which I typed in, but there are some strange characters as for example double "" and /

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use setItem as below:

```
         try {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('email', YOUR_VALUE)
            } catch (error) {
            }
```

For retrive:

```
         AsyncStorage.getItem('email').then((email) => {
                            console.log(email)
                         // YOU CAN KEEP YOUR WHOLE CODE FOR getChatId
                        }).done();
         } catch (error) {
         }
```

Your updated code:

```
///firebaseChatModule.js

getChatId = () => {

try{
  AsyncStorage.getItem('email').then((email) => {
                            console.log(email)
                                const IDloc = firebase.database().ref('/rooms');
    const newChat = IDloc.push({
      title: 'New chat over again'
    });
    const ChatID = newChat.key;
    const membersList = firebase.database().ref('/members').child(ChatID);
    const user1 = email
    console.log('user1: ', user1);
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    membersList.set({
      user1: user1,
      user2: user.email
    });
                        }).done();
         } catch (error) {
         }
  }

//Messages.js

findUserEmail = (email) => {
  firebase.database()
  .ref(`/users`)
  .orderByChild("email")
  .equalTo(email)
  .once("value")
  .then(snapshot => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
     if (email === user.email) {
       Alert.alert("Email is the same as yours!")
     } else {
       if (snapshot.val()) {
         const value = snapshot.val()
         this.setState({ email1: email })
         const email2 = this.state.email1
         AsyncStorage.setItem('email', JSON.stringify(this.state.email1));
         console.log('email1: ', this.state.email1);
         console.log('email2: ', email2);
         FirebaseChatModule.getChatId()
         this.setState({ users: Object.keys(value).map((id) => ({
           id,
           ...value[id]
         })), promptVisible: false})
       } else {
         Alert.alert("Email doesn't exist")
       }
     }
  })
}
```

Comment: So instead of const email2, should I write try{} there?

Comment: I don’t understand where I should write it then.

Comment: If you can share a code with me then I can give your proper code it.

Comment: You need to replace below line:

         AsyncStorage.setItem('email', JSON.stringify(this.state.email1));


with 


         AsyncStorage.setItem('email', this.state.email1);